# Make my game recognize Game Center?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, gamekit

Well, I made my game in iTunes Connect page, enabled Game Center.
I manage to make my game recognize Game Center and work with it.

But now, after some time, I got a couple things messed up, and forgot what setting I needed to change in XCode so my game could recognize Game Center. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

In your frameworks, include the GameKit framework and it should work..

Remember to import the gamekit framework as well whenever you need it in a class..